# c++ binary value for indexed array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I am extremely new to C++ so I'm probably asking a very trivial question, but if you could help that'd be great!

I have an array[n]. 
Indexed from 0 to some unknown value.
I need to access the index of the array, the n value but I need to do so in binary. I am intending to do a bit reversal on it.
So, if I have an array of 2048 points how do I represent the 1024 array in binary?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by binary here or what exactly you want to do.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. See [ask].

Comment: The best way to communicate with other programmers is through code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a value in binary, you can do so in C++14 with

```
int my_binary_value = 0b01010101;
```

If you'd like to test a specific bit of an int, you can do that by masking it, i.e.

```
bool is_bit_4_set = my_binary_value & 0b00001000;
```